# C++ How can I write a method that takes two matrices and calculates the number of rows and columns

Tags: c++, arrays, class, matrix, methods

I am writing a matrix handling class to get some practice with the language.

My first method is this:

```
template<typename T>
T* matrixClass<T>::CreateMat(unsigned int nRow, unsigned int nCol, T& num)
{   
    
    matrixClass::m_nRows = nRow; //number of rows
    matrixClass::m_nCol = nCol;  //number of columns

    matrix = new T[nRow * nCol];//memory allocation
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < nRow; row++) //row selection N x m
    {
        for (unsigned int col = 0; col < nCol; col++)
        {
            matrix[col + row * nCol] = num;   //assigns data to columns n x M
            num += 1.1;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

I am trying to write a method in the same class that takes two matrices created by this method and finds its rows and columns .

Comment: What makes you stop from doing what you want? What is the question?

Comment: Isn't the issue that you're storing the size of the most recently created matrix in a static variable?

Comment: the problem is how can I access the variables nRow and nCol outside of this method.
If only one method is created i can simply write a method that returns them but if two are created it returns only the rows and columns of the latest.

Comment: Correct. You cannot, with this approach. You need to change that.

Comment: I recommend using a `std::vector` rather than `new[]`.

Comment: "I am writing a matrix handling class" Don't. Write a **matrix class** instead. Name in `Matrix`, not `matrixClass`. Have a `Matrix`, rather that `T*`, represent a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical shape of these kinds is something like

```
template <class T>
class Matrix {
  private:
  unsigned int m_nRows, m_nCols;
  T* m_Data;

  public:
  Matrix() = delete;
  Matrix(unsigned int nRow, unsigned int nCol, T* src = nullptr);
  Matrix(const Matrix& orig);
  Matrix(Matrix&& orig);
  Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& orig);
  Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& orig);
  ~Matrix();

  unsigned int rows() const { return m_nRows; }
  unsigned int columns() const { return m_nCols; }
}
```

... or make the constructors private and have `createMat` take over the role of constructing a `Matrix` instance. There are lots of edge cases to discover (or learn) with this approach, so have fun :)

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand how this will give me access to the rows and columns.

Comment: Once you have a `Matrix<T>` instance called `mat`, you can call `mat.rows()` to see how many rows that specific object contains.

Comment: I already have a method ` unsigned int rows() const { return m_nRows; }`, the issue is it return only the latest matrix' rows. And I want to call it inside the class. Thank you for your time btw!

Comment: Right, but yours refer to a `static m_nRows`, which is effectively a global variable. In my example it refers to an instance variable of a `Matrix<T>` object,  of which there can be arbitrarily many.

Comment: I get that, but I want to use .rows() inside a method of the same class, not for example in my main.cpp

Comment: Then you call `this->rows()` or just `rows()`. Take some time to revisit the particulars of instance methods in whatever material you used to learn.

Comment: @ΠάνοςΡεβολίδης Are you using a C++ book? If so, which one?

Comment: c++ primer and I got it working by reminding myself how copying works!